# Highcharts PDF export arabic file name

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using arabic language in some files. when i want to download these files as PDF with arabic file name seems not working with highcharts export server.

```
chart.Exportchart({})
```

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/w4bhbhnb/

Is there any workaround for this in Highcharts?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, got it this is the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/w4bhbhnb/1/

```
chart.Exportchart({})
```